# Data missing when importing a text file into excel

Tags: excel, csv, import, missing-data

i'm trying to import a text file of csv data into excel. The data contains mostly integers but there's one column with strings. I'm using the Data tab of excel professional plus 2019. However, when I select comma as the delimiter i loose 5 of the 16 columns, starting with the one containing strings. The data looks like the below. the date and the 7 numbers are in their own columns (just white space separated) . can anyone help or explain many thanks

```
2143, Wed, 6,Jul,2016, 38,20,03,39,01,24,04,   2198488,    0,  Lancelot  ,  6
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKJua.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeTzl.png)

full data is on https://github.com/CH220/textfileforexcel

Comment: Both your screencaps are the same... Can you also confirm which columns you lose? should we assume "Wed" is the first string?

Comment: Excel can be pretty particular on the format for import from CSV, often the best format depends on your locale settings in Windows.  I am using da-DK, and import to excel worked perfectly on your example here.

Comment: sorry cbernetic nomad ive just updated it. it reduces to 11 columns. MyICQ- what is da-DK please?

Comment: Your first screenshot does not look like it is coming from a text file. It would be more helpful if you posted input data as **text** as an edit to  your question.

Comment: Hi Ron so the screen shots are both from the import data screen in excel. ie once ive selected the text file to import

Comment: What does the dialog on that screen show for File Origin and Delimiter?

Comment: And, as I wrote, access to the original text might be more helpful in figuring out the problem.  That would have to be a copy/paste of the text -- not a screen shot or just typing it in.  Using the text sample in your question, PQ divides it into your expected 16 columns.  Was that a copy paste?

Comment: it shows 1252: western european as file origin and fixed width as delimiter which i then change to comma

Comment: Still unable to reproduce your problem from the data you show in your question.

Comment: in answer to the previous it was a click on data import. what would be the best way to show you the file? its 2,500 lines so bit reluctant to put it in the question? github? thanks again appreciate it

Comment: As a text file, any public sharing site would be OK.  Post the link here.  Github would be fine, as would be onedrive, dropbox, etc.

Comment: https://github.com/CH220/textfileforexcel

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems from the very first line of data in your text file:

```
40,03,52,02,07,20,14,  13137760,    1,  Lancelot  ,  7
```

As you can see, there are only eleven "segments".  Hence, when you try to use the import dialog to separate by comma, there will only be 11 columns even though subsequent rows have 16 columns.

Possible solutions:

- Correct the text file so the first line has the desired number of segments
- Change the Import Dialog, as you did, to comma, then

  - Transform
  - Edit the second line of the generated M-code to change from `Columns=11` to `Columns=16`.  You do this in the Advanced Editor

```
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\new 2.txt"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=16, Encoding=1252]),
```

- Change the `Fixed Width` "argument" from `0,23` => `0`

  - Transform
  - Split Column by delimiter (using the comma) in Power Query.

To me, the "best" way would be to correct the text file.

Comment: knew it would be something simple :) thanks